# Encrypting registry key value

Tags: encryption, batch-file, registry

Dose anybody know if I can encrypt a regestry key value using batch programing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by *encrypt*.

You can set up permissions to stop users getting access, using `regini`.

See `regini /?` for more info, or see this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245031).

To protect the key you specified you can use this

```
regini -m \\1stbyteit-pc C:\regpermissions.txt
```

***regpermissions.txt***

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Software\Blackbird\main\ADMIN_PASSWORD [1 5]
```

I have used `[1 5]` as an example. The list of permission numbers are

```
1  - Administrators Full Access
2  - Administrators Read Access
3  - Administrators Read and Write Access
4  - Administrators Read, Write and Delete Access
5  - Creator Full Access
6  - Creator Read and Write Access
7  - World Full Access
8  - World Read Access
9  - World Read and Write Access
10 - World Read, Write and Delete Access
11 - Power Users Full Access
12 - Power Users Read and Write Access
13 - Power Users Read, Write and Delete Access
14 - System Operators Full Access
15 - System Operators Read and Write Access
16 - System Operators Read, Write and Delete Access
17 - System Full Access
18 - System Read and Write Access
19 - System Read Access
20 - Administrators Read, Write and Execute Access
21 - Interactive User Full Access
22 - Interactive User Read and Write Access
23 - Interactive User Read, Write and Delete Access
```

Comment: The article is a little confusing. 

The key I would like to lock is

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Software\Blackbird\main\ADMIN_PASSWORD

I would like it to be as inaccessible that only the local computer can read the value (or as near as).

Could you show me how to do that?